# How to rewrite for existing rewrite path?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, document-root

I have this code in my .htaccess file that redirects users who go to [www.example.com/inventory/*anySKUnumber*](http://www.example.com/inventory/1980):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Change URL to .../inventory/$row[number]
RewriteRule ^Inventory/([^/]*)$ /Inventory/vendors/php/LandingPage/DirectSKU.php?number=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Now I also want, if the user goes to [www.example.com/inventory](http://www.example.com/inventory) they get redirected to the homepage but I want to keep the same path in the address bar [not just redirect to it].

I get redirected but with an empty path in the address bar when trying this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Change URL to .../inventory/$row[number]
RewriteRule ^Inventory/([^/]*)$ /Inventory/vendors/php/LandingPage/DirectSKU.php?number=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

# Redirect to index but keep path
RewriteRule ^Inventory/?$ /$ [QSA,NC]
```

How do I redirect while keeping the path (http://www.example.com/inventory)?

Comment: Neither of the two rules actually implement a redirection. They won't change the URL visible in the requesting browser. They implement internal rewrites which is what you want. So if you observe a redirection then there must be another cause of this, but not those rules shown here.

Comment: @arkascha that's strange because it's definitely redirecting. Would you know of any way to check what's making it redirect? If I go to any other directory I get the error 404 page

Comment: Either you have other rules in place which you did not mention here, which you might not even be aware of or it is your application logic that does the redirection. Also make sure you are not looking at client side cached results.

Comment: How would I redirect while preserving the path though? Just to familiarize myself for after I debug this lol

Comment: By specifying that a redirection should be performed. I suggest you start reading the documentation of the tool you are using. Don't get this as a rude "RTFM", it simply really does make sense to read the documentation. I never understand why people don't. As typical for OpenSource products the documentation is of _excellent_ quality and comes with great examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: You're right I only skimmed it. I guess the jargon intimidated me lol. I keep having to Google terms. I'll try harder I guess. Thanks for your time

Comment: The issue with googling snippets from everywhere is that you never really understand _why_ things work and _how_ things work internally. You see many variants but it is hard to spot the actual differences that way. It definitely does make sense to sit down and actually study the field one works in. That pays out, obviously.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. It's a hobby of mine and just started this past summer

Comment: We all started this or that way. Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first rewrite rule there is an asterisk used. An asterisk can match zero characters, which is unwanted. Using a plus instead solves the issue. Here is the full code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Change URL to .../Inventory/$row[number]
RewriteRule ^Inventory/([^/]+)$ /vendors/pages/Inventory/LandingPage/DirectSKU.php?number=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

# Redirect to index but keep paths
RewriteRule ^Inventory/?$ index.php [QSA,NC]
```